# Callback not called? Chrome identity API getProfileUserInfo()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

From the Chrome console window of my Chrome app, I'm making these calls:

```
window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(.*?) /)[1];
"37.0.2062.120"
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(console.log)
undefined
```

Why is the callback (console.log) never called?  It should print a userInfo object returned w/o needing network IO.  I'm getting no callback in the console, or in the code run in my app.

The API is here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log` is not a JavaScript function. Pass a function (an anonymous function will do) with an argument to the API call, and see if you get something then. Also, this API requires that the manifest.json file have `"identity"` permission, and (1) you may not have that in the manifest, or (2) you do, but somehow the API call isn't permitted when typing directly to the console (something I personally have never done). If your tests indicate that #2 is a possibility, put the API call into a JavaScript file and try it that way.

Comment: It always irks me that I need to use `function(data){console.log(data);}` for test callbacks. How impure of V8.

Comment: In my chrome app, this worked from the console: `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo){console.log(userInfo)})` thanks!

Comment: Agree, Xan. Perhaps you'd be interested in the LISP interpreter I wrote a few decades ago that was written entirely in LISP? ;-)